# What is not the second derivative of a parametric equation?

Tags: calculus, education

1142004    
Consider the parametric equations $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$. To "find" $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, there are three ways to go: (1) the correct one, that is, $\frac{\frac{d^2y}{{dt}{dx}}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$, and two wrong ones that are (2) $\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}}{\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}$, and (3) taking the derivative of the result of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$, that is, $\frac{
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}·\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}·\frac{dy}{dt}
}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2}$.

Most textbooks warn students to avoid the second one, and to illustrate, work with a concrete example and show the result gained from the second one differs from the first! That is obviously not a constructive approach, to say the least. But, interesting, it is the third approach that is most common, though it looks messy at the first glance. Consider that when working with a concrete example, it is very natural to take the derivative of the result of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (usually written at the right of the equal sign in terms of $t$) and consider it as $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.

The question: Is there any interesting constructive way to convince students that the second and the third is wrong without referring to the first?

Comment: There is a math educators beta SE that this would probably be better for: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm surprised you feel that a counterexample disproving a general statement is not “constructive.”

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I am aware of that. But, for the mathematics involved, I thought it is better to try this one first

Comment: First thing: I think you made a typo in the correct formula; it should be (d^2 y/dtdx)/(dx/dt). Second thing: if you want to eliminate these specific mistakes, you may want to introduce units (say, y are kilograms, x are meters, t are seconds) and assert that the final formula must have the good units (here, kilograms per square meters).

Comment: @D.Thomine Thanks, I corrected that.

Comment: For pedagogical purposes consider parametrization $x=t$, $y=f(x)=f(t)$. Then $d^2x/dt^2=0$, so the wrong formula (2)$ would result in division by zero. This is so manifestly wrong, so killing (2) is easy.

Comment: For the purposes of killing (3) I would use an example with $dx/dt$ negative. If a student divides by $(dx/dt)^2$ instead of the correct $(dx/dt)^3$ (which is what you get from the correct formula), then you get the wrong sign for the second derivative $d^2y/dx^2$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The way you have phrased it makes it surprising. But, let us put this way. Suppose you give students the three options above and ask them to choose one. Thus if you just calculate the result at a certain t, say t=1, what the three result giving you? Just three numbers in which none is a counterexample.

Comment: OK, I think I understand your point now.  I was quibbling on your use of the word *constructive*.  It seemed you did *construct* a counterexample rather than argue generally that it was a false theorem.  So perhaps you build an example where $d^2y/dx^2$ can be computed without parametric equations.  E.g., $y=x^2$, then $x=t^3$, $y=t^6$. Then you have three numbers to check against the one which is definitely correct.  (no time to check if this works.  gotta run to class!)

Answer (score 1):

Write $F(t)$ for the derivative. Where the curve is suitably 'nice', we have that $F(t)$ is in fact given by $F(x(t))$ as the curve locally looks like a function. Now differentiate using the Chain Rule to get

$$\frac{dF}{dt}=\frac{dF}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}\Rightarrow \frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dF}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}.$$

Where of course $\displaystyle F(t)=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ so we have
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}}.$$

That is how I would show the result. For the others I would revert to Matthew's comment.

Comment: It is the exact way that I derive the correct formula. But, one of the current tasks that I gave to students showed me that the temptation of using the third approach is too high when working with a concrete example.

Comment: How do you stop students using the second derivative test incorrectly? e.g. "$f''<0$ at a stationary point implies a min"?

Comment: Pursuant to the Wikipedia article, "symmetry of second derivatives,"    
$$ $$
Can the order of the double differentiation in the top of the correct method (1) be reversed, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the best way to convince students the second and third are wrong is to make certain that they have a clear idea of what they're trying to compute.

While I'm the world's greatest fan of Leibniz notation, I find that in problems like these, it's a rare student who can actually say what $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ might possibly mean; given that problem, it's no surprise that they can't distinguish among different proposed ways to compute it.

I should say that in rare cases, there's a student who *can* compute it without knowing what the heck it might me. In some ways, this worries me even more. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm ready to fill out my second comment to an answer: Consider the parametric curve with equations $x=t^3$, $y=t^6$.  This curve has equation $y=x^2$.  Therefore we know $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2$.

Let's find the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using the parametrization.  We have $\frac{dy}{dt} = 6t^5$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = 3t^2$.  Therefore
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{6t^5}{3t^2} = 2t^3
$$
And this makes sense because $2t^3 = 2x$.

Now apply the proposed second derivative formulas:
$$
\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{6t^2}{3t^2} = 2
\tag{1}
$$
$$
\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}}{\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}} = \frac{30t^4}{6t} = 5t^3
\tag{2}
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = 6t^2
\tag{3}
$$
Only equation (1) provides a second derivative agreeing with our non-parametric result.  So (2) and (3) can't be the right formula.

Comment: I'm going to share this page with my students. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple mnemonic allowing to avoid such wrong approaches. There is a difference of $d^2 x$ and $dx^2$. The first one is the differential linear operator applied twice $d^2 x=d(dx)$; The second is the SQUARE of the result of the differential operator applied once. $dx^2 =(dx)^2$. So $d^2 y / dx^2$ cannot be 
$d^2 y/d^2 x$.